# New field on Database user registration

Tags: php, jquery, database

Hi Guys i'm a student and have a problem!

Hope someone can help!

RingCaptha number get saved in the s_phone_land

i try to add a field in the Database for this.
I find all this files with s_phone_land

File: ring_captcha/index.php
I change this from > to

FROM

```
if (osc_get_preference('save_number', 'ring_captcha') == '1') {
    Params::setParam('s_phone_land', $user_phone);
}
```

TO

```
if (osc_get_preference('save_number', 'ring_captcha') == '1') {
    Params::setParam('s_phone_verified', $user_phone);
}
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/UserActions.php
How to add s_phone_verified here?

```
if(!$this->is_admin) {
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userName', $input['s_name']);
    $phone = ($input['s_phone_mobile'])? $input['s_phone_mobile'] : $input['s_phone_land'];
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userPhone', $phone);
}
```

I add this on line 283:

```
$input['s_phone_verified'] = trim(Params::getParam('s_phone_verified'));
```

How to add s_phone_verified here?

```
//we are logged in... let's go!
Session::newInstance()->_set('userId', $user['pk_i_id']);
Session::newInstance()->_set('userName', $user['s_name']);
Session::newInstance()->_set('userEmail', $user['s_email']);
$phone = ($user['s_phone_mobile']) ? $user['s_phone_mobile'] : $user['s_phone_land'];
Session::newInstance()->_set('userPhone', $phone);
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/controller/register.php
How to add s_phone_verified here?

```
if($success) {
    // Auto-login
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userId', $user['pk_i_id']);
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userName', $user['s_name']);
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userEmail', $user['s_email']);
    $phone = ($user['s_phone_mobile']) ? $user['s_phone_mobile'] : $user['s_phone_land'];
    Session::newInstance()->_set('userPhone', $phone);
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/frm/User.form.class.php
I add this on line 73:

```
    static public function phone_verified_text($user = null) {
        parent::generic_input_text("s_phone_verified", isset($user['s_phone_verified'])? $user['s_phone_verified'] : '', null, false);
    }
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hUsers.php
How to add s_phone_verified here?

```
//can already be a logged user or not, we'll take a look into the cookie
if ( Cookie::newInstance()->get_value('oc_userId') != '' && Cookie::newInstance()->get_value('oc_userSecret') != '') {
    $user = User::newInstance()->findByIdSecret( Cookie::newInstance()->get_value('oc_userId'), Cookie::newInstance()->get_value('oc_userSecret') );
    View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView('_loggedUser', $user);
    if(isset($user['b_enabled']) && $user['b_enabled']==1) {
        Session::newInstance()->_set('userId', $user['pk_i_id']);
        Session::newInstance()->_set('userName', $user['s_name']);
        Session::newInstance()->_set('userEmail', $user['s_email']);
        $phone = ($user['s_phone_mobile'])? $user['s_phone_mobile'] : $user['s_phone_land'];
        Session::newInstance()->_set('userPhone', $phone);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I add this on line 347:

```
/**
 * Gets cell phone of current user
 *
 * @return string
 */
function osc_user_phone_verified() {
    return (string) osc_user_field("s_phone_verified");
}
```

I change this one from > to

FROM

```
/**
 * Gets phone_land if exist, else if exist return phone_mobile,
 * else return string blank
 * @return string
 */
function osc_user_phone() {
    if(osc_user_field("s_phone_land")!="") {
        return osc_user_field("s_phone_land");
    } else if(osc_user_field("s_phone_mobile")!="") {
        return osc_user_field("s_phone_mobile");
    }
    return "";
}
```

TO

```
/**
 * Gets phone_land if exist, else if exist return phone_mobile,
 * else return string blank
 * @return string
 */
function osc_user_phone() {
    if(osc_user_field("s_phone_verified")!="") {
        return osc_user_field("s_phone_verified");
    } else if(osc_user_field("s_phone_mobile")!="") {
        return osc_user_field("s_phone_mobile");
    } else if(osc_user_field("s_phone_land")!="") {
        return osc_user_field("s_phone_land");
    }
    return "";
}
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/installer/struct.sql
I add this on line 120:

```
s_phone_verified VARCHAR(45),
```

File: oc-includes/osclass/model/User.php
I add this on line 56:

```
's_phone_verified',
```

I hope someone can help!

Thanks

Comment: Why is this question tagged as jquery?